# How can I manipulate dates on each line in a file using only minimal *nix tools?

Tags: linux, openwrt

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rCLH4r4M
I have a text file: "hogyaza.txt".
I want to convert the "normal dates" in it [only at the line starting] to unix time. i know how to "convert" one line:

`$ ONELINE='2011-01-24 19:13:19ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1'; date +%s -d "$(echo $ONELINE | awk -F "ASDF" '{print $1}')"`
`1295892799`
`$`
But i need it in this format:
`1295892799ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1`
or better, this format:
`1295892799 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1`
here's the file:
`$ cat hogyaza.txt`
`2011-01-24 19:13:19ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1`
`2011-01-24 19:13:19ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPOFFER(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1`
`2011-01-24 19:13:19ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1`
`2011-01-24 19:13:19ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1`
`$`

Does anybody know how to convert the e.g.: "^2011-01-24 19:13:19" dates to unix format in the txt?
Thank you!
p.s.: it's needed on an openwrt router, so no perl :((( no space for it on the flash

Comment: What version of AWK (Busybox, `gawk`, other)? If you have `gawk` can you use features specific to it or do you need portability?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/237229/sed-to-unix-time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to convert one line, then a simple loop will handle all the lines for you:

```
while read line; do
    orig_date=$(echo "$line" | awk -F "ASDF" '{print $1}')
    new_date=$(date +%s -d "$orig_date")

    echo "$line" | awk -F "ASDF" -vdate=$new_date -vOFS="ASDF" '{$1=date; print}'
done < hogyaza.txt
```

This gives output that looks like:

```
1295914399ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1
1295914399ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPOFFER(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1
1295914399ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1
1295914399ASDF 01 24 19:13:19 router daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1140]: DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.201 00:1b:37:a8:74:f1
```